# insert via XML in Database without knowing datatype

Tags: xml, database, insert-query

I am creating a utility that will insert records in the DB from the XML as usually happened in the DBUnit(Java).

I want to know how I can manage the data types when I am creating a query? e.g. Employee is a table and the inner Elements are fields of them.

```
<Employee>
    <firstName>Sohail</firstName>
    <lastName>Hussain</lastName>
    <salary>100000</salary>
</Employee>
```

In the above xml, I can't predict either salary is int or not? So, when I am creating an inline query it would be,

```
Insert into Employee(firstName, lastName, salary)
values ('Sohail', 'Hussain', '10000')
```

In the query you can see 10000 is in a quote, how can I achieve this functionality without adding some more tags in the XML to make it complex.

Answer (score 0):

First my question is which database you are using ?

I am not sure how you are preparing the query but parsing mechanism available in SQL Server

```
Declare @XmlData XML

Set XmlData ='<Employee>
<firstName>Sohail</firstName>
<lastName>Hussain</lastName>
<salary>100000</salary>
```

```
    Declare @MapData Table (firstname varchar(100),lastname varchar(100),salary int )

    INSERT INTO @MapData
    SELECT  
           Tbl.Col.value('firstName[1]', 'varchar(100)'),  
           Tbl.Col.value('lastName[1]', 'varchar(100)'),  
           Tbl.Col.value('salary[1]', 'int')
    FROM   @XmlData.nodes('//Employee') Tbl(Col)
```

Now you have values in @MapData table variable and you can use as you want

result can be seen

```
          select * from @MapData
```

It will raise the error if the parsing get failed. So use this parsing statement in try catch block. and if parsing gets fail that means the input data is not valid.

Comment: It's not about the DB, I am simply using inline query that may use SQL Server or other DB. Here in the example you are hardcoding salary int and it looks like in SP. First Off, I am just creating inline query by XML in C# that use SQLCommand (just for your ease).

Comment: What is the schema of your table? what is the type of salary field in your table ? You have to decide at the time of defining schema. And then you can modify the insert query accordingly. Is it possible to ceate the table without defining schema ?

Comment: I tried to perform bulk insert which is far batter option than inline insert in loop. Reset is up to you.